# How to approve the In-process script approvals in Jenkins programmatically through Jenkinsfile(scripted one)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, devops

www.jenkins-server.com:8087//scriptApproval/ is my Jenkins server

could any one help me how can approve the scripts without any manual interruption

Answer (score 0):

To approve the in process script in Jenkins you may want to use the method of ScriptApproval#approveSignature
def signature = 'new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic' org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval